# Standard google drive android-demo is not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have downloaded the demo from: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos added the necessary credential in the Google Cloud Console. I have created an Oath cliendId and mentioned the SHA1 signature.

The application is loading but on clicking any of the links it is giving the error in the mobile app as

> Unknown issue with Google Play services

Also in the logcat the messages are as follows:

```
10-16 00:27:57.915  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Internal error occurred. Please see logs for detailed information
10-16 00:27:59.305  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo D/GestureDetector﹕ [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-16 00:28:00.240  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-16 00:28:00.240  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-16 00:28:01.370  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo D/GestureDetector﹕ [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-16 00:28:01.845  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-16 00:28:01.845  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-16 00:28:02.645  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo I/BaseDriveActivity﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
10-16 00:28:02.650  17648-17648/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Internal error occurred. Please see logs for detailed information
```

Please help me debug this further.

PS:

I added this line in the BaseDemoActivity.onResume() method:

```
 showMessage("isGooglePlayServicesAvailable:"
            +     GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()));
```

and it is returning 0, which represent SUCCESS

Comment: Is google play services installed on the device?

Comment: @danny117: Yes, it is Android version 4.1.2, and I clearly see Google Play Services [its version in mobile is 6.1.74] in the Application Manager.

Comment: Did you have to mention the Google Cloud project id somewhere in the code?